# Calling tablview controller from another tableview controller in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift5

I'm very new to Swift and if you have recommendations on how to improve this, I'd appreciate it.

I have two ViewControllers, they look exactly the same, except the data. For some reason my second ViewController doesn't work. It seems my tableView has a nil value and I'm seeing:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

. The way I'm calling my ViewController like so present(MenuViewController(), animated: true)

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
let db = Firestore.firestore()

var names = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    db.collection("Menus").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print ("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                self.names.append(document.documentID)
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}


}


extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("tap tab revolution")
}
}

extension MenuViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.names.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Which value is causing the crash exactly? Which line?

Comment: Actually I posted the wrong code, just realized that, I was trying to make my tableView optional. When I'm trying to get tableView.delegate, I find out that value is null

Comment: Where is MenuViewController tableView? On. a Xib? On a Storyboard? Is it linked? My guess, it's in a Storyboard.

Comment: It's on a  storyboard, I currently have two classes, one is MenuViewController, then I have just the default ViewController, which is calling this

Comment: `MenuViewController()`that's not calling a `MenuViewController` linked with he Storyboard (and so where is connected the tableview). Either you should use a segue, or do a search on how init a viewcontroller from a storyboard (plenty of question already).

Comment: Oh awesome, that makes it work, but now it's doing this weird thing where it's floating over my screen, any idea why?

Comment: You are presenting it. That’s normal in iOS 13. Check the presentation options : fullscreen etc. Or did you want to push it ?

Comment: Oh great that works, thank you!

Comment: Hey, I just got banned from asking questions on here, do you mind answering another question?